# Passing form params to url_for/redirect_to/render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some url

```
  get '/vacancies/:id(/:mode)', to: 'vacancies#show', as: 'vacancy', constraints: { mode: /(resume|file)/}
```

inside show view user can fill in the form and send request to the server.
If User sent not valid params I should redirect him back, show validation error and also I should keep filled in params.

How can I implement this stuff?

upd1

Typical rails solution for this is something like `render :new` or `render :edit`, but in my case I can't do `render :show` because is rendering view for `'/vacancies/:id` route not for `'/vacancies/:id(/:mode)`.

Also I tried do `redirect_to :back` and this works fine except one thing: params are not passed through request.

I guess there is solution inside `response` object, but didn't find yet

upd2

```
class VacanciesController < ApplicationController
  # vacancies/:id - is just show view
  # vacancies/:id/resume - is show view with form
  # vacancirs/:id/file - is show view with form for sending pdf|doc|etc
  def show
    @vacancy = Vacancy.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    if Vacancy::SaveResume.new(resume_params).call.valid?
      redirect_to vacancies_path
    else
      # didn't know what to do there
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is very basic Rails stuff. I suggest giving [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) a read and then posting a more detailed question if you're still stuck.

Comment: @Thilo I just updated post

Comment: you'd better use ajax in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, in order to maintain those params, you would re-render that same view template instead of redirecting. This happens a lot with the new and create action, but the same priniciple applies anywhere, such as displaying a form in a show action.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    render :new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to :show
    else
      render :new # re-render another template
    end
  end
end
```